# Function modifiers body

Tags: blockchain, remix, solidity-0.8.x

we know that modifiers are kind of security levels added to functions, but why should modifier body contain `_;`, if we don't use this symbol we get the error :

> SyntaxError: Modifier body does not contain '_'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function modifier is checked before the function. `_;` essentially states that the rest of the function can be executed here. It might be tempting to think that this is unnecessary. However, what's often missed is that there could be code after `_;`

```js
modifier noReentrancy() {
    require(!locked, "No reentrancy");
    locked = true;
        
    _;
        
    locked = false;
}
```

Here, the `require` statement and `locked=true;` will be run before the rest of the function. And once the function is done, `locked = false;` will be executed.

I hope the significance of having a seperator `_;` is clearer now.

Comment: Great, I see, the missed part is that we can add code after the separator _; thank you so much !